# How can i pop back in navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have six `viewControllers`. On `viewController1` I have a `button` which takes me to the `viewController6`.

Now from `viewController6` I want to pop back to `viewController5`, `viewController4`, `viewController3`, `viewController2` and `viewController1` respectively.

How can I do this?

Comment: You have 2 ways to navigate with the navigation controller. You can "pop" if a controller was already shown (pushed) before    `[self.navigationController popToViewController:<UIViewController> animated:BOOL]`
or you can "push" the controller if it is showing for a firs time
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:<UIViewController > animated:BOOL]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
```

Insert your required view controllers in order using

```
[allViewControllers insertObject:viewControllerX atIndex:requiredIndex];
```

If you want to replace only previous viewController use,

```
 [allViewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:indexRequired withObject:viewControlerX];
```

Then set back the navigation stack,

```
self.navigationController.viewControllers = allViewControllers;
```

Then you can use following to pop back to any viewController :

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: @Aunsha, i have bug into above method. When i click on button on VC1 this takes me to VC6. From VC6 i could successfully perform pop back. When again pressing button in VC1 this takes me to VC6. But when i swipe from VC6, this takes me to VC1 instead of VC5 and so on...how do i solve this..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` if you want to pop just 1 `ViewController`, or use `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to go back to the fist `ViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is Possible .

if you want to pop `1 ViewController` from controller stack

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

go back to the `fist ViewController`.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

For More Information use this Link

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Hi Dixit, thanks for the reply. But i think you did not get my question. First i want to go to VC6 from VC1 using a button click and then from VC6 i want to move back to VC5, VC4,VC3,VC2 and to VC1.

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
popToViewController:animated
```

or

```
setViewControllers:animated
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [self.navigationController pushViewController:]
in this order:
from ViewController1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2.

And use [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:] to go from ViewController2 to 1.